# Grab Multiple Rows MYSQL Join

Tags: mysql, wordpress

This applies to WordPress / Woocommerce

I'm using this query to grab a specific `meta_value based` matching `post_ids` in `wp_postmeta` and `wp_posts`

```
SELECT meta.meta_value
FROM wp_postmeta AS meta
JOIN wp_posts AS o
ON meta.post_id = o.ID
WHERE o.post_type = 'shop_order' AND o.post_status='wc-cancelled' AND meta.meta_key='_billing_email' 
ORDER BY o.post_date DESC
```

My problem is I also want to get `meta.meta_keys = '_billing_first_name'` and `'_billing_last_name'` for those same conditions in the same query.  Right now I have to get each row separately then combine them on an excel sheet.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can (OUTER) join the table twice, giving it a unique alias each time. Or make a pivot query using (for instance `...MAX(CASE WHEN...THEN..END) x`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, a simple `OR` or using `IN` will do

```
SELECT meta.meta_value
FROM wp_postmeta AS meta
JOIN wp_posts AS o
ON meta.post_id = o.ID
WHERE o.post_type = 'shop_order' AND o.post_status='wc-cancelled'
  AND meta.meta_key IN ('_billing_email' , '_billing_first_name', '_billing_last_name')
ORDER BY o.post_date DESC
```